# Error on R studio startup

Tags: r, rstudio

I get the following error message in the console when opening Rstudio :

> Error installing package: Error: ERROR: no packages specified
>   The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

My R version is 3.1.1

Answer (score 2):

This is the error you get from calling `install.packages` with no package specified.

```
> install.packages()
Error in install.packages() : no packages were specified
```

You might want to check whether something like that is included in your Rprofile.site file.